# IOS linkedin integration (Send Connection Request, Search People)

Tags: iphone, ios, oauth, linkedin-api

I'm using the linkedin OAuth sdk.

I have the oauth functionality working and my iPhone App is able to successfully logged in to LinkedIn.

i want to implement these two things.

1. I want to search people using the JSON protocol.
2. I want to send connection request people which i got from search.

Please provide me assistance asap. suggest me Sample codes if any.

thanks in advance.

Comment: this page would seem to give you what you need... https://developer.linkedin.com/apis

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't offer you specific answer for your question, but you should check on this open-source project.

[LinkedIn Share for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/linkedin-share)