# Not able to implement linkedin integration for iPad

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

[image]I am getting login window with option "allow access" button instead "signin and allow access" button while implementing linkedin with iPad, thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13851932/344798.

Please do a basic search before posting a new question.

Comment: Hi,sorry to mention that,i have done linkedin integration for iPhone,but my problem is when i try to implement linkedin integration for iPad, i am getting the login window with option like "allow access" button only instead "signin and allow access" button,do i additionally need to add any code for iPad integration

Comment: update your question with images for the problem you are having. It may happen if you are already logged in.